# how to segregate lists and document libraries in sharepoint 2013 as we see that in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

So i have a local navigation where i need to show List library and Documents library folders separately as we see two different views in sharepoint 2010

Do we have a way to show the same in Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use OOB 'Quick Launch' to maintain navigation nodes manually, you need to create custom navigation provider to render navigation nodes.

[Custom navigation provider in SharePoint 2013](http://pranavnk.blogspot.com/2016/08/custom-navigation-provider-in.html)

[image]

Comment: So that was not my requirement My requirement was like i need a heading which shows Libraries and if we click on it then it should show only document libraries but not sharepoint lists or anything and the same case applies to list also